# What API's are available to a custom application to notify Tivoli Service Request Manager (TSRM) of errors?

Tags: java, api, tivoli

Our company recently purchased IBM's Tivoli Service Request Manager (aka TSRM) for managing our "catalog of IT services" (note, this does not necessarily mean web services, but what services do we as a department offer the company, like password resetting, etc.), as well as the Help Center and second-level support "portal". We also plan on using it for our change management processes (and have purchased other Tivoli products for said future purchase).

Anyway... We have several WebSphere-based Java applications and also some standalone applications that don't run inside a container. We are hoping to connect our applications to TSRM so that if there are some more "serious" or "fatal" errors in our application, they can send "events" to TSRM and open service request (ie, help) tickets for our support team. The thought is that our support team can get the jump on a problem before end users call in.

We already have TSRM set up such that if we send an error to Help_Center@ourEmailAddress.com it will automatically create a ticket within TSRM. I am wondering...is there another set of API's available to our applications? Such as a web service API, or a messaging API or something that we could send to as well, or is this email option the only one?

Any one else have experience working with TSRM and custom applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it looks like using email is the best and really only way to talk to TSRM. There are other hooks (both JAX-WS and REST form), but they don't work in the way we want (automatic ticket creation). So for now, this will be the answer, unless someone else can figure it out and provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may integrate you applications with TSRM through Integration Composer. If you are not willing to purchase it, then use an external system and create your own web service.

Comment: How do you integrate with Integration Composer? Does it have web services? If so, which? JAX-WS? REST? Does it support JMS? Any other API?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to use TDI (Tivoli directory integrator) to move data from your applications to TSRM and create Service Requests. You can also search for MAXIMO ENTERPRISE ADAPTER for integration to TSRM